# How to send Spark driver logs to history server? (Standalone Mode)

Tags: apache-spark

Many of our Spark applications running with cluster mode have failures due to errors from the Driver. I setup a spark history server which read from **spark.eventLog.dir**, everything works fine, The history server is able to reconstruct application UIs but no driver logs can be found.

Also I check for list of applications listed under **spark.eventLog.dir**, but everything is started with app-****, I could not find any driver-******.

How can I configure driver logs to be sent to **spark.eventLog.dir**?

Comment: Driver logs can't go to spark.eventLog.dir.

Comment: It could be a valid assumption since I could not find anything related from the official docs. When it is still not clear, hope some can give a solution, or workaround at least.